# CXF web service with multiple parameters

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I'm developing a web service using Camel and CXF and use "code first" approach.
Everything works fine for methods having a single parameter. Methods with multiple parameters however receive only the first param, others resolve to nulls. No exception is thrown.

Here is my route:

```
<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:serverEndPoint" />
  <log message=">>> data is : ${body}"/>
  <choice>
    <when>
      <simple>${in.header.operationName} == 'doSomething'</simple>
      <to uri="bean:TestWSBean?method=doSomething"/>
    </when>
    ...
</route>
```

Server endpoint is defined as follows:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serverEndPoint"
               address="http://localhost:9000/casServer/"
               serviceClass="com.test.iface.TestWebService">
  <cxf:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inInterceptors>                   
  <cxf:outInterceptors>
      <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:outInterceptors>                   
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And the implementation bean itself:

```
@WebService
public interface TestWebService {
  public String doSomething(String one, String two);
}
```

My question is pretty basic, what should be done to be able to send multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use the requestwrappper annotation. Take a look at code generated by the wsdl_first example in cxf. It generates the annotations and a suitable wrapper class.

@RequestWrapper(localName = "updateCustomer", targetNamespace = "http://customerservice.example.com/", className = "com.example.customerservice.UpdateCustomer")

Comment: Thanks Christian, it works for me. However, it requires a lot of annotations, which is not acceptable in my case (code is generated). I will have to re-factor the interface to wrap multiple parameters with a single class.

Comment: How to use it? Does camel needs any headers to be send inside route?